# Profiling a function in framework

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling

I use some framework and found that some function ( for example, Rebuild(param1, param2) ) sometimes works very slow.

How to gather information about every function call (for detecting the longest call & params) ?

Recommendations to modify sources or call function outside framework are not suitable.

Comment: It will be good to do it without independent external tools.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you very sleepy (http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy). It is a profiling tool very easy to use.

- It will show the time passed in the function. (the inclusive and exclusive time passed in the function all given in seconds and in percentage of application execution)
- You will also have the callstack of your function.
- And some other thing you will discover by yourself.

You just have to run it and attach it to the process you want to profile. It will not require to (re)compile any source code.

Answer (score 0):

My 1st idea might be to use code coverage tools (e.g. [gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html)) to check which code paths are stressed with certain test situations, where you observe this behavior.

Additionally injected profiling code (how many calls with CPU time profile, e.g. [GPROF](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial/)) will help further figuring out your bottlenecks.

Both techniques aren't intrusive to any source code, but require recompilation using certain compiler flags (GCC).

I'm pretty sure MS Visual Studio will offer similar tools.